# Django Rest Framework: How to pass parameters to save method for cascading

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

How can I pass a parameter to the `save()` method on my serializer in DRF?

More specifically, I need to pass the `cascade=True` flag to the save method.
I am using DRF with MongoDB and I have an Reference Document document that I want saved when the Parent Document is saved. From what I understand Mongoengine provides the cascade flag for this purpose. Otherwise I get this error:

> ValidationError (Event:None) (You can only reference documents once
>   they have been saved to the database:

Now how do I get that cascading working with my serializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override [how Django REST Framework saves objects](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances) by overriding the `create` and `update` methods on the serializer.

```
class MyMongoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        from rest_framework.serializers import raise_errors_on_nested_writes

        raise_errors_on_nested_writes('update', self, validated_data)

        for attr, value in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance, attr, value)

        # Override how the save happens
        instance.save(cascade=True)

        return instance
```

You may also be having issues because of the `create` method on the serializer. It does not use `obj.save`, but instead uses `Model.objects.create`.